# Copy program: File Permission Denied

Tags: c, linux, unix, permissions, system-calls

My following program, which copies a file, won't allow me to copy files because of "permission denied". However, I gave it permissions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fdinput, fdoutput; //file pointers
    char arrbuf[5000]; //size of what can be read in file
    ssize_t bytesR, bytesW;//number of what input returns

    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH |S_IXOTH ;

    fdinput = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY); //pointing to read file

    fdoutput = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY);//pointing to write file

    if(fdinput == -1){
    perror("the source file cant be opened");
    return 1;
    }

    if(fdoutput == -1){
    perror("the written file cant be opened");
    return 2;
    }

    while((bytesR = read(fdinput, arrbuf, sizeof arrbuf)) > 0){
        bytesW = write(fdoutput, arrbuf, (ssize_t) bytesR);
    }

    close(fdinput);
    close(fdoutput);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: forgot to ask the question. My program wont allow me to copy a file because of permission denied and i gave it permissions

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanations? error message etc?

Comment: Edit your question into your question — don't make it into a comment.

Comment: Are you copying an executable program?  If not, the `S_IXUSR` and `S_IXOTH` bits are inappropriate in the permissions (and the omission of `S_IXGRP` is puzzling given that you include the other two).  Note that your second `open()` call tramples the error status (in `errno`) from the first — if both failed.  Your `open()` for writing doesn't attempt to create the file if it doesn't already exist, which is probably as well since you omitted the permissions argument that would be needed if you included `O_CREAT`.  If you create, consider `O_TRUNC` or `O_EXCL` too.

Comment: What is the purpose of defining and initialising `mode`?, without ever using it?

Comment: i changed the fdoutput to else after the first if statement, but now its telling me bad address

Comment: i used the mode because at first i couldnt get permission, but now i have bad address as the error

Comment: What is the name of the source file you're copying, and the target file you're copying to?  If the target file does not exist yet, your program won't create it.  You can only copy over an existing file with that code.  The `mode` variable is unused — you seem to be confused about this as you keep saying it is used but the code shows that it is not used.  Or perhaps you aren't showing us the real code — which is an appalling mistake to make.  We can't analyze bugs in an approximation to the code you're running. You should error report immediately after each `open()` call.

Comment: so i created two txt files and tried to copy one to another, but i tried that just now and it gave me permission denied after the adjustments. the source files exist, but permission is not granted

Comment: gcc filehw1.c
[user]$ ./a.out
the source file cant be opened: Bad address
[user]$ ./filehw1.c simpledata.txt samplecontext.txt
-bash: ./filehw1.c: Permission denied
[user]$ vi filehw1.c

Comment: I don't think you're executing your program the right way. You know you run the binary with `$ ./a.out simpledata.txt samplecontent.txt` right? You can't directly execute the `filehw1.c` source file. That's probably why it's telling you "Permission denied". `a.out` is the binary, `filehw1.c` is just the source file.

Comment: You are not checking argc to determine if you are passing the filenames, so executing "a.out" with no arguments will give you "Bad address".... which was one of your error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the call to the *system call* `open()` for the *destination* file (i.e.: the file to be created as a result of the copy):

```
fdoutput = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY);
```

#### Making possible the creation of the destination file

First, the call above to `open()` opens the file with the given name by `argv[2]`, **only if it already exits**. Otherwise, the system call fails (`errno` is set to `ENOENT`) and `perror()` produces:

> the written file cant be opened: No such file or directory

In order to create the file if it does not exist yet, the `O_CREAT` flag has to *ORed* together with `O_WRONLY`.

#### Truncating  an already existing destination file

If the destination file already exist you surely want to **truncate the length of that already existing file to zero** at the moment of `open()`ing. That can by achieved by *ORing* the `O_TRUNC` flag together with the other flags.

#### Providing the permissions for the file to be created

Let's look at the `open()` system call's prototype:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

The `...` at the end is to specify a kind of optional argument. That argument is used by `open()` only when a new file is being created. It provides the *mode bits* to be applied for the file to be created. This is not exactly the permissions for the file to be created, but it is strongly related to them (for more info see: *[file mode creation mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)*).

You created `mode` of type `mode_t` but just forgot to pass it to `open()`.

---

With all exposed above in mind, your call should look like:

```
fdoutput = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode);
```